# How to achieve On Demand loading of JS Files in MVC Architecture of ExtJS 4.1.3?

Tags: extjs

In an enterprise application we may have large no of JS files in our application. To load such a huge no of files at first place will take more time which is directly proportional to initial loading time of our application.

Is their any mechanism for loading JS file On Demand i.e. as an when they are required ??

Can anybody tell me how would i take full advantage of Ext.require([]) in ExtJS ??

Answer (score 1):

**By requiring all classes that you will use in each file. This is also very important when you want to create a production version of your app.** Seealso de process of minification in this guides:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/getting_started

"**Ext JS 4 comes with a system for dynamically loading only the JavaScript resources necessary to run your app**. In our example Ext.create creates an instance of Ext.container.Viewport. When Ext.create is called the loader will first check to see if Ext.container.Viewport has been defined. If it is undefined the loader will try to load the JavaScript file that contains the code for Ext.container.Viewport before instantiating the viewport object. In our example the Viewport.js file gets loaded successfully, but the loader detects that files are being loaded in a less-than optimal manner. Since we are loading the Viewport.js file only when an instance of Ext.container.Viewport is requested, execution of the code is stopped until that file has been loaded successfully, causing a short delay. This delay would be compounded if we had several calls to Ext.create, because the application would wait for each file to load before requesting the next one.

To fix this, we can add this one line of code above the call to Ext.application:

`Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport');`"

This will ensure that the file containing the code for Ext.container.Viewport is loaded before the application runs. You should no longer see the Ext.Loader warning when you refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

But by doing so your application performance would actually suffer. ExtJs framework contains few hundreds files and load them individually would talk much more time then load 1-2 minified files containing all your application.

Did you build (i.e. concat and minified) your application?